# Error with uploading my google chrome extnsion to chrome web store

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Hey guys i have planned to upload my google chrome.

According to the documentation i have made the whole file in a zip format with the manifest.json in the root directory. i have developed the solution with reactjs

But when i select the file and uploaded it to the web store it shows me error like

An error occurred: Failed to process your item.
Invalid package. Please make sure it is a valid zip file and the file manifest.json is at the root directory of the zip package.

Can anyone tell me why am getting like this ??..

Any help would be appreciated ..Thanx in advance

Comment: Double click on your ZIP file.
If you see a folder with the same name as the ZIP file, that's no good.

Comment: i think the compressed format of the mac is not well decompressed, i used online zip converter and it worked well